# Using MD5 in symfony2 security.yml for legacy users

Tags: php, symfony, hash

I have a legacy system which contains md5 hashed passwords. I have tested these to be correct and they do not use a salt.

**security.yml**

```
security:
    encoders:
        Namespace\MyBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: md5
providers:
    entityUsers:
        entity: { class: NamespaceBundle:User, property: username }
```

In my User entity I have implemented UserInterface and made sure the **salt is set to the empty string**.

But I get a **bad credentials** error when trying to authenticate.

I have tried switching security.yml to plaintext and entered the hash and the system works fine.

Surely md5 should just work?

Comment: If your salt is empty, the default password encoder would ignore it.

Answer (score 26):

I was having exactly the same problem and had to dig into the code to find out why.

**You don't need to create a custom encoder.**

By default, the `MessageDigestPasswordEncoder` encoder (`Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\MessageDigestPasswordEncoder`) in Symfony 2.5 - and possibly all Symfony 2 releases - calculates the MD5 hash of the raw password, with/without using a salt, as expected, *and then re-hashes the MD5 a number of times (5000 times, by default, in Symfony 2.5)*.  To make things that little bit more exciting, *the encoder will also base64-encode the hash, by default*.  Both of those features were causing problems for me.

You can fix the problem(s) by disabling the re-hashing and/or disabling the base64 encoding, in `security.yml`, thus:

```
security:
    encoders:
        Namespace\Of\Your\User: 
            algorithm: md5
            encode_as_base64: false
            iterations: 0
```

Hope that saves you some time.

Comment: This works perfectly fine for me in Symfony 3 for legacy user with password encoded as `md5('password')`. This setup makes encoder work just like simple `md5` function call and this is exactly what I needed in my setup.

Answer (score 6):

Turns out that the md5 in symfony2 uses a salt by default. There may be an easier way, but I just created a **custom md5 password encoder interface** that ignores salt.

**Register a service**

```
namespace.project.md5password.encoder:
    class: Namepspace\MyBundle\Services\CustomMd5PasswordEncoder
```

Create the **encoder service**

```
namespace Namespace\MyBundle\Services;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\PasswordEncoderInterface;

class CustomMd5PasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoderInterface
{
    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function encodePassword($raw, $salt) {
        return md5($raw);
    }

    public function isPasswordValid($encoded, $raw, $salt) {
        return md5($raw) == $encoded;
    }
}
```

**Use the new service in security.yml**

```
security:
    encoders:
        Namespace\MyBundle\Entity\User:
            id: namespace.project.md5password.encoder
```

Hope this helps