# Migrate legacy user md5 to FOS User

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.3

I have an application that I want to migrate on Symfony3, but I have some problems.
As the title says I want to migrate user table within Symfony3.
I use FOS User Bundle for login, but my legacy users don't have salt.
The password was encrypted with md5 encryption. I saw few explanation about this problem and I follow that explanation but this doesn't work for me. 
Here is my code.

this is security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: 
            id: trgovina_lea.legacy_encoder

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
                # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

this is custom encoder service

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\PasswordEncoderInterface;

class LegacyEncoder implements PasswordEncoderInterface
{
    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function encodePassword($raw, $salt) {
        return md5($raw);
    }

    public function isPasswordValid($encoded, $raw, $salt) {
        return $encoded === $this->encodePassword( $raw, $salt );
    }

}
```

So I need to login user with md5 password without salt.

I saw a few examples like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24680752

But this not solve my proble also. It always return invalid credentials.

Thnak you guys